# Internal Webservice IIS .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, soap, internal

We have two sites on one IIS 7.5 server.  Site B needs to talk to Site A through a SOAP service (Site B used to be external hence using SOAP, but now they are on the same server).

How can I reference Site A in Site B's web config without having a roundtrip through the absolute path http://www.example.com/webservice/endpoint.asmx?

Essentially I want

```
      <endpoint address="foolocalhost/webservice/endpoint.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap"
    contract="Reference.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap" />
```

Rather than

```
      <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/webservice/endpoint.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap"
    contract="Reference.WebServiceSoap" name="WebServiceSoap" />
```

Would I need to change my host file to set foolocalhost up as a binding?  Or is there an easier way around it using just the IIS GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a hosts record seems to be the easiest way.  IIS 7.5 doesn't require a restart to pick up the changes so it's negligible whether there's an other solution.  This method won't disrupt any production environment.

The record to be entered in hosts on this example would be

```
127.0.0.1 foolocalhost
```

You would then go into your bindings in IIS and enter a binding e.g.

Type - http
Hostname - foolocalhost
Port - 80
IP Address - *

Now when site B tries to communicate with site A it shouldn't leave the network, since it resolves back to itself.

Further reading on how to edit hosts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5d4GykliBEw